# Play scala, java.sql.date throws me errors, trying to build a to-do form

Tags: java, mysql, scala

I'm trying to build a [to-do list](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList) using play. Now the issue I'm having, is that I can't seem to use the SQL format Date in my parser.

```
package models


import java.sql.Date

import anorm.SqlParser._
import anorm._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB

case class Task(
                 id:Int,
                 task:String,
                 description:String,
                 dueDate:Date
)

object Task {

  val task = {
    get[Int]("id") ~
      get[String]("task")~
      get[String]("description")~
      get[Date]("dueDate")map {
      case id~task~description~dueDate => Task(id, task, description, dueDate)
    }
  }

  def all(): List[Task] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select * from task").as(task *)
  }

  def create(task: String, description: String, dueDate:Date): Unit = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("insert into task(task, description, dueDate) values ({task},{description},{dueDate})")
        .on(
          'task -> task,
          'description -> description,
          'dueDate -> dueDate
        ).executeUpdate()

    }
  }

  def delete(id: Int) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("delete from task where id = {id}")
        .on('id -> id).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

}
```

getDate throws me the following error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter extractor: anorm.Column[java.sql.Date]

When I change SQL Date to util Date, it'll whine that SQL Date is expected. The parameter dueDate should become the SQL column whith custom dates as input.

How do I fix this? Is it even possible to use java.sql.date in Scala?

(Im using h2-db for my SQL)

If you need more info, leave a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `java.sql.Date` for your domain model. Use `java.time.LocalDate` or `org.joda.time.LocalDate` instead; anorm's `Column` type knows how to handle these by default.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't fixed it yet, but vytah explained it a bit more on reddit.com/r/scala Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write your own implicit conversion. Something like this:

```
import anorm._

implicit def toSqlDateColumn = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
  val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
  value match {
    case date: java.sql.Date => Right(date)
    case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(s"Cannot convert $value : ${value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass} to java.sql.Date for column $qualified"))
  }
}
```

Comment: This results in type mismatch; found : (Symbol, java.sql.Date) required: anorm.NamedParameter at    'dueDate -> dueDate

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using java.util.Date the following should work

Replace

`get[Date]("dueDate")`

with

`date("dueDate")`

Comment: This results in more pain and suffering as I don't get an error, but it just blanks my page :p

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by default it uses java.util.Date. See the `date` method in the `SqlParser` docs:

[play docs anorm.sqlParsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#anorm.SqlParser$)